# How to back again banner if the gets last banner in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

Hi how i'am to back again my banner. if the gets last banner and back again to early banner. Thanks Before Guys

This example my code :

```
    //Banner Variable
    private int currentPage = -1;
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 0;

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable update = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES - 1) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            vpbanner.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(update);
        }
    }, 1000, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code solve your problem :-

```
vpbanner.setCurrentItem(currentPage == 0 ? 4 : 0, true);
```